# Refugee family Reunion (UKVI)

Tags: united-kingdom, family

I applied for my children Reunion Application under 352D of immigration rules. Children ages are 8 years,10 years and 14 years. ECO refused applications under 352D(iii). I have been remained in constant contact with my children and also sending them money. I was also in contact with children schools, teachers and carer/guardian(children are living with their grandmother). 
How can I rebut it in the court? 
If you have any authority, experience or any material plz share with me.
Especially I request qualified professionals.

Comment: Which country are you talking about?

Comment: [UK](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&ei=kMvVXNKVKIjYsAWj7KpA&q=immigration+rules+352d&oq=immigration+rules+352d&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.1538343.1546404..1547775...0.0..0.205.1801.20j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i67j0i131j0i131i67j0i22i30j0i22i10i30.sFx81_DcczI)

Comment: I believe this question belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  Can you post it there and include an image of the refusal letter with identifying information blacked out?

Comment: Any question about rebutting in court is going to require a lawyer.